# when commit will affect actually tables while procedure call?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with ms sql with struts framework.
While calling procedure I put autocommit false in program.
when the procedure run I have to commit one seperate transaction and it must be affect the table externally
But it never be save until conn.commit() statement execute in program.
Is it any other way to commit the transaction in procedure itself, to affect the table on the end of the single transaction in procedure?
Pl. tell me if you know.

T.Saravanan

Comment: Retagged, the Java part is irrelevant in this question

Answer (score 1):

You should start and commit/rollback a transaction at the same level, otherwise you are introducing a lot of unpredictable paths - and frankly some bad design. So: if you need to commit at the server, use `BEGIN TRAN` / `COMMIT TRAN` in the TSQL to handle the transaction locally.

Note, though, that TSQL exception/error handling is not as rich as handling errors at a caller such as java/C#. If the problem is that you want to disassociate this work from another unrelated transaction, then it depends on how your calling code works:

- if it is using connection-level transactions, then you will need to use a separate connection; just run the transaction on a different connection using the java/C#/whatever transaction API (i.e. the same as your existing code, by the sound of it, but on a different connection)
- if it is using things like scope-based transactions (`TransactionScope` in C#; not sure about java etc - but this is an LTM or DTC transaction) then you can explicitly create a new scope that is bound to either a *new* (isolated) transaction, or the nil-transaction (i.e. the inner scope is not enlisted)

As for affecting the tables... SQL Server generally does optimistic changes, i.e. **yes** the changes are applied immediately (so that commit is cheap, and rollback is more expensive) - however, the ***isolation level*** will generally prevent other SPIDs from seeing the data. A competing SPID with a low isolation level (or using the `NOLOCK` hint) will see the uncommitted data, but this may be a phantom/non-repeatable read if the data eventually gets rolled back.